# Several urls for a submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Suppose you have a git project with a submodule which can be accessed via several urls, say `$url1` and `$url2` (which are suppored to be synced). In the team, some people don't have access to `$url1`, and other people don't have access to `$url2`.

Is it possible, in git, to add a submodule with "either `$url1` or `$url2`", such that if `$url1` is not reachable, it tries `$url2`?